# Can I work with a socket I created in another file in python?

Tags: python, eclipse, sockets, python-3.x

When I create a socket in python (a simple TCP socket for example), can I call / use it in another class? And if not, how can I do it?
Thanks from a python beginner ^^

Comment: It depends on how you want to use it. If you're importing a class that created a socket, you may be able to access it. Can you give us more details?

Comment: I want to create a TCP socket automaticly with an instance, but I want to use it in a method of another object. I imported the first class into the second, but my eclipse still tells me, that my socket import in the second object still isn't in use, so I'm not sure whether it's working. (Not far enough in progress for debugging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has no concept of 'private' data members. Accessing members of a class is as simple as using their name, ie:

```
import socket

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

class B:
    def send(self, host, port):
        # send msg through A
        a = A()    
        a.sock.connect((host, port))
        a.sock.sendall('Hello, world')
```

Comment: If you like the answer -- can u click 'answered'?